# How to build and deploy Angular Universal (Prerender) application to Netlify

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-universal, netlify

so I learned about the `Angular Universal` and wanted to make my web app a static SSR app (prerendered). I want to deploy the web app to Netlify.

- I added the `nguniversal` to my application.
- Should I build it with `ng build --prod` or `npm run prerender`?

I am not sure about how to build this application.
I am totally confused that what is the correct way to build this application and did not find anything useful in the documentation that how should you build the `nguniversal` application.

For deployment, I'm currently connecting my GitHub repo to Netlify for easy deployment.

I hope, I will find the correct answer here! :)